# Wörterbücher der Uni Trier – umgezogen oder eingestellt?

Tags: dialect, resource, dictionary

Unter der Adresse der [Uni Trier](http://germazope.uni-trier.de/Projects/WBB/lemmasearch) gab es noch bis vor kurzem, und über viele Jahre, mehrere Wörterbücher – teils zu dieser Region, namentlich ein Rheinisches Wörterbuch und ein Pfälzerwörterbuch, aber auch weitere, überregionale. Nun sind sie fort, und ich finde sie nicht wieder; die Seite zeigt einen Site-Error.

Weiß jemand, ob die Seite umgezogen ist, und wohin? Oder einfach nicht weiter gepflegt wird, dichtgemacht wurde, eingegangen ist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es gibt jetzt anscheinend eine eigene Adresse (Domain) für die Wörterbücher:

http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/

Rechte liegen beim Kompetenzzentrum für elektronische Erschließungs- und Publikationsverfahren in den Geisteswissenschaften an der Universität Trier.

Comment: Oh, wunderbar, alle wieder da, und noch viel mehr! Dass die nicht selbst eine Weiterleitung eingerichtet haben ...